# Call same promise inside `Then`

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I want to know if you can call the same promise twice like so

```js
//receiver is sent if the mail should be sent to someone else and will have a
//different email boy

const body = (req.body.receiver) === undefined ? 'regular mail': 'admin email body'

//the sendEmail Function takes to, from and body arguments
await sendEmail(req.body.requestedBy, someEmailAddress, body)
        .then(info => {
          console.log(info)
         //a mail should be sent only to requester if req.body.receiver is present in the request
          if (req.body.receiver) {
            await sendEmail(req.body.receiver, someEmailAddress, body)
              .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
              })
          }
          return res.send(data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error:', err)
        })
```

Of course this would be wrapped in an async function because the sendMail function i created returns a promise. Mail is sent via nodemailer.

Comment: no, you can't call the same promise twice (can promises even be called?). You can however do what you're doing and call the same function twice.

Comment: so just do
 `await sendEmail(req.body.requestedBy, someEmailAddress, body).then().catch()
sendEmail(req.body.requestedBy, someEmailAddress, body).then().catch()`  ?
@KevinB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing in your example is not technically calling the same promise twice. You are calling the same function twice, `sendMail`. Each time you call that function, it returns a new promise.

So the answer is yes, you can call that function multiple times even though it returns a promise, because it will return a new promise each time.

Comment: Yes calling the same function twice sorry. So what I'm doing is correct and possible? @boric

Comment: Yes, calling the same function twice will work fine, even though the function returns a promise, because it is returning a new promise object each time it is called.